# How to determine if element is last or first child of parent in javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code, emulating a click on the left or right key down events. This is used as part of a gallery slideshow:

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
                    if(e.keyCode == 37) { // left
                        $(".thumb-selected").prev().trigger('click');
                    }
                    else if(e.keyCode == 39) { // right
                        $("thumb-selected").next().trigger('click');
                    }
                });
```

Essentially it picks the next or previous sibling (depending on the key pressed) and call the click event that will in turn display the appropriate image in the gallery. These images are all stored in a unordered list.

Where I am stumped is that when the first or last image is selected and the left or right button is clicked (respectively), I want it to get the next picture at the opposite end of the list of images. For example, if the first image is selected and the left arrow is pressed; given that there is no previous image (or li element), it will get the last image in the list. This way the keys never lose functionality.

Is there a function in jquery that will either check if the present element is the first or last child of its parent, or return its index relative to its parent so I can compare its index to the size() (child count) of his parent element?

Comment: You could ask the parent object what the first/last children were and compare with the current element. No idea on performance.

Comment: Performance is not an issue. From what I've read it's impossible to compare two selector elements (as objects). I could try to compare the id's, but no id's are set on the list items, which are automatically generated by the script. I'm trying to modify the script the least possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var length = $('#images_container li').length;
    if(e.keyCode == 37) { // left
         if($('.thumb-selected').index() > 0)
              $(".thumb-selected").prev().trigger('click');
         else
              $('.thumb-container').eq(length-1).trigger('click');
     }

     else if(e.keyCode == 39) { // right
         if($('.thumb-selected').index() < length-1)
             $("thumb-selected").next().trigger('click');
          else
              $('.thumb-container').eq(0).trigger('click');
     }
```

`.thumb-container` is the parent element of the all the thumbs. At least what I got from your code.

HTML

```
    <ul class="thumb-container">
        <li>thumb</li>
        <li>thumb</li>
            .
            .
            .
    </ul>
```

Comment: Yes that is the structure of the list. The index() call seems to work. I'll give this a try.

Comment: This worked great. Only variation in my code is that when calling the li element at the other side of the list (when the if conditionals fail), my selector is $(".li .thumb-container li") with a simple last() or first() function to point to the right element to trigger.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this in native JavaScript like so:

```
var thumbSelected = document.querySelector('.thumb-selected');

var parent = thumbSelected.parentNode;

if (thumbSelected == parent.firstElementChild) {
    // thumbSelected is the first child
} else if (thumbSelected == parent.lastElementChild) {
    // thumbSelected is the last child
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`is()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/is/) method to test:

```
if( $(".thumb-selected").is( ':first-child' ) ) {
    // whatever
} else if( $(".thumb-selected").is( ':last-child' ) ) {
    // whatever
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) which returns the index of the element or you could use prev() and next() to check if there is one more element.

```
if(e.keyCode == 37) { // left
    if($(".thumb-selected").prev().length > 0)){
        $(".thumb-selected").prev().trigger('click');
     }else{
        //no more elements                     
      }
}
else if(e.keyCode == 39) { // right
    if($(".thumb-selected").next().length > 0)){
        $(".thumb-selected").next().trigger('click');
     }else{
        //no more elements                     
      }
}
```

EDIT - i updated the code because it makes more sense to use next() and prev() instead of nextAll() and prevAll()

Comment: prevAll() looked like a good idea, I'm not sure why prev() would be better to get the length. Regardless, neither seem to work (returns 0 all the time). I'll start reading into this function; will let you know what I find.

Comment: What do you mean it retunrs 0?Look here (http://jsfiddle.net/NkWRK/)  or show us your markup. prev() and next() are better because i just look at one element, they are faster